# What to take on a 9-Day Bahamas cruise (specifically undies)

Tags: clothing, cruising, laundry

My wife on I are about to go on our very first cruise, and its a Disney cruise to the Bahamas.

Well, I'm here at work and she just asked me how many pairs of socks and underwear to bring on the cruise. I am always one to pack a lot of socks and underwear, as I like to change them out if I feel like I'm getting to sweaty...

So, I started thinking it through...

Say we wake up (put on socks and undies), do a couple of things on the boat, go swimming (take off socks and undies), get out of the pool and do dinner (put on new socks and undies), maybe go swimming after (take off socks and undies), and then go out to the night-club (put on new socks and undies if we swam twice, so lets say this step happens half of the days), then go to bed.

For 9 days, and that day plan, by my calculations, that 25 pairs of both socks and undies for each of us! Someone please help me out! That can't be right! If so, I've got a lot of stuff to buy! Thanks!

Comment: [Disney cruises have full service and 24-hour self service guest laundries](http://disneycruise.disney.go.com/ships-activities/ships/services/guest-services/).   Far better than lugging all that stuff with you!

Comment: Hey! Alright! There's so much to learn about these cruises its easy to skip over small parts like that. Thanks @MarkMayo ! I hope the laundry service isn't too expensive.

Comment: @pnuts that is absolutely terrible advise. I have done what you suggested on hiking trips and camping excursions, but this is a freaking cruise that I spent thousands of dollars on for my wife and my anniversary. I'm not wearing my dirty underwear inside-out and sleeping in a tent on the deck. Get real.

Comment: I'm with pnuts here, being a few pairs of pants short isn't the end of the world, especially as it sounds like you're only going to be wearing each pair for about 4 hours max. Anyway as @MarkMayo said, there's laundry on the ship. I imagine there's also a place to buy extra underwear.

Comment: If I don't feel like a king on this boat, I'm gonna be one mad mo-fo. Let's just keep in mind that I want the best experience possible. This is a very big deal to me.

Comment: I don't know about the disny cruiseships, but I went the self-laundry route on an Alaskan cruise (small to midsize boat) and the only way to get the laundry done in a timely manner was to do it first thing in the morning or skip a shore excursion.

Comment: You don't always have to put on fresh underwear? If you've worn it for only a couple of hours, shouldn't be noticable if you put them on again. Also, just wear swimwear for breakfast if you know you are going to follow that with a swim?

Comment: Going commando... for some reason sounds delightful. Same with swimwear for breakfast. Yet putting underwear back on, underwear that was only worn for four hours tops and in all states of logic would be perfectly fine to put back on, still grosses me out, and I can't explain why. I just imagine chaffing and getting bumps from it or something. Eww...

Comment: You'll only chafe if it's wet. You'll smell if you got it wet (sweat), then let it dry and put back on. If you've just strolled around for an hour or two in the morning, its no worries (you don't *change* your underwear every 2 hours, right? Nothing has happened to it while you left it folded in a corner) . If you can't convince yourself of that though, and will think about your underwear all the time while wearing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"If I don't feel like a king on this boat, I'm gonna be one mad mo-fo". Sounds like you're setting yourself up for disappointment, expectation wise, but anyway 25 pairs of underwear and socks takes up little room, you could just bring them if it makes you feel better. Self-serve laundry sounds a bit painful as one of the other comments indicated- finding machines that are available and slow drying.

'Room Service" laundry costs actually look pretty reasonable if [this](http://disneycruiselineblog.com/2013/01/onboard-self-and-full-service-laundry-and-dry-cleaning/) blog is fairly accurate and up-to-date. Hotels can be insanely expensive.

[image]

Rush service is +50% or +100% of the prices, as it says.

Comment: True @pnuts and thank you, but I think I have all of the information I need now. I am not sure where you found this, but thank you very much. I really hope this is not per item, otherwise this is very expensive.

Comment: It is per item.

Comment: $30/person (assuming you cut your luggage by half, and only take 12 sets of socks/underwear) seems fairly cheap for a ship. That's just 7 bottles of water!

Comment: @Kent That's what I'd do. Just cut it in half (do laundry halfway through) and forget about the cost. It's not a big %. Keep things in perspective.